# Show the inverse state of a model in a checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Let's say I have a model such as:

```
required: bool
```

and a checkbox labeled `Optional [x]`.

When the model value of `required` is `true`, `Optional` should be unchecked, and vice versa.

Is there a way I can bind the `required` model value to a checkbox, but invert the shown value and the value that would be set when the checkbox is clicked?

I know I can create a `$watch` and do the thing on my own, but I thought maybe Angular provides some facility for that kind of stuff.

Comment: have you tried ng-checked?

Comment: would this work on the checkbox?: ``ng-model="optional" ng-change="required = !optional"``

Comment: and for the inital value use: ``ng-value="!required"``

Comment: @BettySt Yes, that worked exactly as I expected. Thank you :)

Comment: @alexandernst ok for I posted it as answer for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for the checkbox input:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="optional" ng-change="required = !optional" ng-value="!required" />
```

You need `ng-value` for the initial model value.

Comment: I used `ng-init="optional = !required"` instead of the ng-value.